# how to make php scripts executable instead of downloadable using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant, backend

Recently I set up a virtual machine through vagrant and I'm using nginx as a web server. The OS I'm using for the VM is Ubuntu Linux 12.04. The problem is that any script I write in PHP gets downloaded, instead of being executed on the browser. Seeing as the PHP interpreter is normally installed I figured I'd post here the config file of nginx, as this is where the problem is likely to be found. Being a novice in the world of web development, I can't figure out what is out of the ordinary, can you guys take a look and tell me if you see something wrong? Thanks.

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;
  root /vagrant/www/web;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  #strip app.php/ prefix if it is present
  rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

  location / {
    index app.php;
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
  }

  location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening socket
  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
  }

  # enable global phpMyAdmin
  location /phpmyadmin {
    root /usr/share/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      root /usr/share/;
      fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
      root /usr/share/;
    }
  }
  location /phpMyAdmin {
    rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was my suspicion the problem was in this location block:

```
location ~ ^/(app|app_dev)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix://var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
  }
```

The parameter to the location directive is a regular expression that defines only two possible file names: app.php and app_dev.php, thus making any other filename non-executable. For this to change, one needs to either add the names of one's php scripts to the parameter or change the regular expression to a more inclusive form as per Frederic Henri's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having double `//` to indicate the `fastcgi_pass` path of php in your location block, try this instead

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_keep_conn on;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param  HTTPS              off;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't do it.

Could it be that the regex parameter in the location directive is creating all the problems? The way I read this is that it won't run anything other than "app.php" or "app_dev.php".

Comment: right, the best would be to have something generic like `location ~ \.php$ ` but really the issue for the app.php file not being executed was the double / to reference path so `//var/run/php5-fpm.sock` was wrong and need to replaced by `/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`

Comment: I changed that to a single "/" but to no avail. And testing both app and app_dev, I found out that the server actually executes them. I will mess with the parameter and see what happens.

Comment: No the problem is that the server executes ONLY app.php or app_dev.php and every other script it downloads.